# How to extract users from multiple AD

Tags: powershell, active-directory, csv

I need to extract a file containing all of my AD's. I am trying to do so with Get-ADuser. However, since the -Searchbase does not accept multiple sources,I did something like this:

```
    'DC=AD1,DC=net','DC=1D2,DC=net','DC=AD3,DC=net','DC=AD4,DC=net' |
foreach-object{
get-aduser -SearchBase $_ -Filter { ( Enabled -eq $True ) -and ( (sn -ne 'Empty') -or (givenName  -ne 'empty')) -and ( (telephoneNumber -ne 'empty') -or (mobile -ne 'empty'))} -Properties * |Select sn,givenName,title,department,company,telephoneNumber,mobile,mail,employeeType,physicalDeliveryOfficeName,extensionAttribute15 | Export-CSV "c:\temp\Liste_collaborateurs.csv" -Encoding UTF8 -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
}
```

But when I run it, I get this error 3 times :

> get-aduser : The supplied distinguishedName must belong to one of the following partition(s): 'DC=bva,DC=net ,
>   CN=Configuration,DC=bva,DC=net , CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=bva,DC=net , DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=bva,DC=net ,
>   DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=bva,DC=net'.
>   At C:\Users\adm.wfd\Desktop\getaduser.ps1:3 char:1
>   + get-aduser -SearchBase $_ -Filter { ( Enabled -eq $True ) -and ( (sn -ne 'Empty' ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADUser], ArgumentException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Comm
>      ands.GetADUser

I guess the 3 times are for each AD my server isn't connected to. 
I can't run my command on each DC...

How can I get my csv with all my users on a single server ?

Thanks for your replies

Comment: Did you try using the `-Server` switch? You can specify the hostname of your DC you wish to query. `get-aduser -SearchBase $_  -Server DC01`

Comment: I tyied using  the -Server option but i get the same error :/
I can only use this parameter once and only on the domain my server is.

Comment: My bad, use the FQDN. `-Server DC01.domain01.com`  `-Server DC02.domain02.com`  etc

Comment: When I try using it with the FQDN, it works only with the domain I'm onOherwise, with multiple iterations of server i get:
`Get-ADUser : Cannot bind parameter because parameter 'Server' is specified more than once. To provide multip
to parameters that can accept multiple values, use the array syntax. For example, "-parameter value1,value2,
At C:\Users\adm.wfd\Desktop\getaduser.ps1:3 char:54
+ get-aduser -SearchBase $_ -Server VBLG-Dom01.bva.net -Server VBMS-Dom ...
+                                                      ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADUser],`

Comment: Can you post the code you're running in your OP?

Comment: Try `$servers = @("DC=AD1,DC=net","DC=1D2,DC=net","DC=AD3,DC=net","DC=AD4,DC=net" )

foreach ($server in $servers) {
Get-AdUser -server $server
}` dont forget to add your filter

Comment: with your suggestion I get :                                             
`Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Server'. Specified
method is not supported.`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using the right domain controllers? Or the spelling and order fits?
I tested your script in my own environment with multiple domain controllers and it worked. Your error message only appeared if I entered the wrong information.

Does the command work with the individual domain controllers when not executed in the loop?

What if you started your script directly on the domain controller?

I didn't test it myself.

Like that.

```
$Servers = 'server1','server2'            
ForEach ($Server in $Servers) {            
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server -ScriptBlock {            
        get-aduser -Filter { ( Enabled -eq $True ) -and ( (sn -ne 'Empty') -or (givenName  -ne 'empty')) -and ( (telephoneNumber -ne 'empty') -or (mobile -ne 'empty'))} -Properties * |Select sn,givenName,title,department,company,telephoneNumber,mobile,mail,employeeType,physicalDeliveryOfficeName,extensionAttribute15 | Export-CSV "c:\temp\Liste_collaborateurs.csv" -Encoding UTF8 -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation         
    }            
}
```

Comment: The get-aduser works perfectly well when used with only 1 AD. I checked in case I made mistakes with my domain names but everything is OK, for the spelling part at least.
I tried by switching the $_ part with one AD. I tried in the loop and out of the loop.The only one working is the one ms server is registered on.

When you says wrong informations, which informations could be wrong except the domain names ?

Comment: With information I meant the domain names.

Comment: They are correct.